# Segfault when calling, but not jumping to, address in rax

Tags: c++, assembly, posix, x86-64, abi

I'm working with an assembler-like API (it's not *really* an assembler, but it can emit machine code) that I am debugging and toying with. It's specifically for System V x86_64 ABI, so I'm only going to be talking about SysV calling conventions and such.

For some reason, when I emit some contrived code like this, for testing purposes

```
builder.emit_sub(rsp, 1);
builder.emit_movq_vr(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&hello_world), rax);
builder.emit_call(rax);
builder.emit_add(rsp, 1);
builder.emit_ret();
```

a segmentation fault occurs at the call (when it is run, not when being assembled), and yet

```
builder.emit_movq_vr(reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&hello_world), rax);
builder.emit_jmp(rax);
```

succeeds just fine. The point of failure seems to be at the `call` instruction, but I don't know what is bugging out the pseudo-assembler. It might be emitting the wrong opcode operands or something, but I'm not sure. The raw emitted machine code looks something like this for the buggy code, alongside the opcode that it is supposed to represent, as printed by some simple debug statements

```
sub    48 81 EC 01 00 00 00
movqvr 48 B8 63 80 AA 01 01 00 00 00
call   FF D0
add    48 81 C4 01 00 00 00
ret    C3
```

Remark: `movqvr` is not a real instruction [mnemonic]; the `vr` at the end is just a debug annotation to me saying it's a "move imm64 to reg" kind of instruction.

Remark: The `sub` and `add` are to align the stack on a 16-byte boundary, which I believe is a necessity in this ABI. They could've been better written as a `push rax` and a `pop rax` (or `pop rcx` if `rax` is needed for a return value), but ignore that, unless it is this that is messing up the call (e.g. if `rsp` is not being modified correctly).

Comment: Are you emitting a `sub rsp, 1` and relative add? Are you sure this will align the stack? Not sure what may be the problem, is the stack set up correctly?

Comment: `sub rsp, 1` doesn't seem right to align to a 16-byte boundary maybe you meant `sub rsp, 8` and `add rsp, 8`

Comment: Oh man, talk about off-by-one errors. More like off by 7!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the System V ABI, the stack is aligned to a 16-byte boundary *before* every `call` instruction.  Thus, on function entry it takes another **8** bytes (not 1) to reach the next 16-byte boundary.  Remember that in C, pointer differences are scaled by `sizeof(type)`, but in asm they aren't.

And yes, `push rax` / `pop rcx` would be a good choice, and is what clang / LLVM does if it doesn't already need to push an odd number of call-preserved registers or reserve any extra stack space.  If you do need to reserve any stack space for locals, use an offset that will leave `rsp` 16-byte aligned.

---

BTW, you could save code size by using the `sub r/m64, imm8` encoding when the immediate fits in a sign-extended 8-bit value (i.e. `if ((int8_t)imm == imm)`).  Also, if you ever need to add / subtract +128, note that `-128` fits in an imm8, so you can `add rsp, -128` (e.g. after an odd number of `push` instructions).

If you know the address where your code will run from, you should use the `call rel32` encoding, rather than a register-indirect call.  But you're right that jumping to an arbitrary 64-bit address requires this `mov r64, imm64` sequence, not a direct `call`.

---

Did you use a debugger to find out where `hello_world` crashed?  Maybe if it calls `printf` (rather than `puts`), it forgot to zero `al` (with `xor eax,eax`) to indicate no FP args in XMM registers, so maybe printf used some 16-byte SSE alignement-required stores to the stack?

Having RSP not even qword-aligned is very bad, but I wouldn't expect it to have crashed anything that would crash with it 8-byte aligned (but not 16).

Comment: Yeah, accidentally subtracting 1 instead of 8 from rsp seems to be the problem. The reason why I'm subtracting an imm32 instead is because the naïve "generator" doesn't assume that the stack size will always be representable by an imm8. And no, the generated code does not itself call debug functions, but the "assembler" does.

Comment: @MonatheMonad: right, that's why I suggested *checking* `(int8_t)imm == (int32_t)imm` in `emit_add` to decide which opcode to use, when you get around to optimizing the code-gen.

Comment: @MonatheMonad: IDK what you mean about "calling debug functions".  I mean you should run the generated code (or the whole thing) under `gdb`, so you can see exactly where it crashes.  (And notice the value of `rsp`...)  Also, you get the benefit of having disassembly output from `binutils`'s disassembly code, in case your built-in code dumps are bogus.

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't be so lazy with the debugging. This whole project is just for fun, anyway.

Comment: @MonatheMonad: Using a debugger for asm is more important than any other language, I find.  It's very easy to do stuff in asm that assembles but crashes, and a debugger gives you vastly more info than "it crashes".  Also, the relevant machine state has a very small size (often just registers), and the way you think about asm (in terms of the machine-state steps necessary to implement your algorithm) is exactly what you need for single-stepping to make sense.  Developing asm without a debugger is like trying to build a robot blindfolded.  You can, but it's much harder.